# How to get the first and last index as per same key/value pair of consucative records using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to fetch the first and last index of same key/value pair from array of objects using java script. I am explaining the input data below.

```
const array= [
        {id:"1", name:"A"},
        {id:"2", name:"A"},
        {id:"3", name:"A"},
        {id:"4", name:"B"},
        {id:"5", name:"B"},
        {id:"6", name:"C"},
        {id:"7", name:"C"},
        {id:"8", name:"C"},
        {id:"9", name:"A"}
        {id:"10", name:"A"}
        {id:"11", name:"D"}
];
```

Here I have some array of objects and there are some duplicate data present inside it. I need to extract the fist and last index of only the duplicate data those are present conservatively but for single record I don't need to calculate the index. So as per requirement my expected output should like below.

```
const output = [
       {"start":0,"end":2},///for A
       {"start":3,"end":4},// For B
       {"start":5,"end":7},// For C
       {"start":8,"end":9},// Again For A
]
```

So here I need to calculate the index of duplicate key value pair of each object which are present conservatively.

Comment: Show us what you've tried first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce` to solve your problem:

```
const array= [
        {id:"1", name:"A"},
        {id:"2", name:"A"},
        {id:"3", name:"A"},
        {id:"4", name:"B"},
        {id:"5", name:"B"},
        {id:"6", name:"C"},
        {id:"7", name:"C"},
        {id:"8", name:"C"},
        {id:"9", name:"A"},
        {id:"10", name:"A"},
        {id:"11", name:"D"}
];

const output = array.reduce((acc, item, key) => {
    if (key > 0 && array[key-1].name === item.name) {
        if (acc.length && acc[acc.length-1].end === key-1) {
            acc[acc.length-1].end = key;
        } else {
            acc.push({start: key-1, end: key});
        }
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```