# exceljs mergeCell by first and last value on each row

Tags: javascript, exceljs

for example i have console log and the print is look like these

```
workSheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, function(row, rowNumber){
    row.eachCell(function(cell, colNumber){
  if (rowNumber >= 7 && colNumber == 1) {
     console.log(`rowNumber : ${rowNumber} || cell.text : ${cell.text}`);
  }
 }
}
```

```
rowNumber : 7 || cell.text : YOGI
rowNumber : 8 || cell.text : YOGI
rowNumber : 9 || cell.text : YOGI
rowNumber : 10 || cell.text : ARIF
rowNumber : 11 || cell.text : WIDODO
rowNumber : 12 || cell.text : WIDODO
rowNumber : 13 || cell.text : JOHN
rowNumber : 14 || cell.text : EXCEL
rowNumber : 15 || cell.text : EXCEL
```

then how i can manipulation to get first and last of rownumber by on same value, if i do on manual its would like these

```
workSheet.mergeCells(`A7`, `A9`);
// workSheet.mergeCells(`A10`, `A10`); // on single would skip
workSheet.mergeCells(`A11`, `A12`);
// workSheet.mergeCells(`A13`, `A13`); // on single would skip
workSheet.mergeCells(`A14`, `A15`);
```

similar on https://stackoverflow.com/a/62231988/8122500
i have manipulation the output code like these

```
const array= [
        {id:"7", name:"YOGI"},
        {id:"8", name:"YOGI"},
        {id:"9", name:"YOGI"},
        {id:"10", name:"YOGI"},
        {id:"11", name:"YOGI"},
        {id:"12", name:"WIDODO"},
        {id:"13", name:"WIDODO"},
        {id:"14", name:"WIDODO"},
];

const output = array.reduce((acc, item, key) => {
    if (key > 0 && array[key-1].name === item.name) {
        if (acc.length && acc[acc.length-1].end === key-1) {
            acc[acc.length-1].end = key;
        } else {
            acc.push({
              start: array[key-1].id, 
              end: key
             });
        }
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
output.forEach(el => {
  console.log(`start : ${el.start} , end ${el.end}`);
})
```

but the print is look like these

```
start : 7 , end 9
start : 9 , end 11
start : 12 , end 14
```

what i expected :

```
start : 7 , end 11
start : 12 , end 14
```

Comment: already solved i got tricky on last sytnx and modified like these ```console.log(`start : ${el.start} , end ${array[el.end].id}`);```

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question and mark that as the answer. That way someone else who might stumble onto your question in the future will know what the issue was

Answer (score 0):

already solved i got tricky on last sytnx and modified like these

```
console.log(`start : ${el.start} , end ${array[el.end].id}`);
```

in similar comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/62231988/8122500 , i modified on if else body {}, these the part of code.

```
if (acc.length && acc[acc.length-1].end === key-1) {

+            acc[acc.length-1].end = key;
-            // acc[acc.length-1].end = key;

        } else {

-            // acc.push({start: key-1, end: key});
+            acc.push({
+              start: array[key-1].id, 
+              end: key
+            });
        }
```

the result is

```
start : 7 , end 11
start : 12 , end 14
```